# How to create a request like VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest, but for detecting a whole human body, not just faces?

Tags: ios, swift, image-recognition, coreml, apple-vision

I would like to create a request like **VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest**, but for detecting and giving the position of a **whole human body**.

Is that possible with **Vision** framework?

If so, what are the steps for accomplishing that?

Comment: With Vision you can request what is provided by Apple. Until (and unless) they do that kind of request, you can't.

Comment: You could, on the other hand, use something like this: https://github.com/infocom-tpo/PoseNet-CoreML